# Do Until loop need to restart on error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Do Until loop in VBA.

My problem is that there is likely to be an error most days when running the macro as not all the sheets will have info on them.

When that happens I just want to start the loop again.  I am assuming its not the "On Error Resume Next" I was thinking of counting the rows on the autofilter and then if it was 1 (ie only titles) starting the loop again.  Just not sure how to do that.

Dim rngDates As Range 'range where date is pasted on.
'Dim strDate As String
Dim intNoOfRows As Integer
Dim rng As Range

```
Sub Dates()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set rngWorksheetNames = Worksheets("info sheet").Range("a1")


dbleDate = Worksheets("front sheet").Range("f13")


Worksheets("info sheet").Activate
Range("a1").Activate

Do Until ActiveCell = ""

strSheet = ActiveCell

Set wsFiltering = Worksheets(strSheet)

intLastRow = wsFiltering.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row

Set rngFilter = wsFiltering.Range("a1:a" & intLastRow)

With rngFilter

.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

On Error Resume Next

Set rngDates = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


End With

With rngDates
.Value = dbleDate
.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

If wsFiltering.FilterMode Then
wsFiltering.ShowAllData
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("front sheet").Select

MsgBox ("Dates updated")

Loop
```

Comment: Does your data have headers?

Comment: in which line you expect to have an error?

Comment: Any of the sheets could have an error - it might change day on day as there would be no data for that day.

Comment: I managed to sort it using the do until loop by breaking up the if statement for the intnoofrows into two bits.  Some of the code repeated itself as there was common bits but it now seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check existance of data after filtering by using SUBTOTAL formula.

```
If Application.WorkSheetFunction.Subtotal(103,ActiveSheet.Columns(1)) > 1 Then

'There is data

Else

'There is no data (just header row)

End If
```

You can read about SUBTOTAL [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx%5d)

---

Rather than using the `Do Until` loop, consider using a `For Each` loop on the Worksheets Collection.

ie.

```
Sub ForEachWorksheetExample()

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    'go to error handler if there is an error
    On Error GoTo err

        'loop through all the worksheets in this workbook
        For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            'excute code if the sheet is not the summary page
            'and if there is some data in the worksheet (CountA)
            '(this may have to be adjusted if you have header rows)
            If sht.Name <> "front sheet" And _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sht.Cells) > 0 Then

            'do some stuff in here. Refer to sht as the current worksheet

            End If

        Next sht

    Exit Sub

err:
    MsgBox err.Description

End Sub
```

Also. I would recommend removing the `On Error Resume Next`  statement. It is much better to deal detect and deal with errors rather than ignore them. It could cause strange results.

Comment: I checked using the countif lines for ones that are visible.  But not sure how to then get the macro to start the loop again if there is no data.  If that makes any sense?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run the macro on another worksheet? Can you post the rest of the Sub, not just the loop? I suspect that you may be better restructuring your code a bit, I will try to help.

Comment: I have updated the code to include it all thank you.  @Sam Ward  Also not sure if a for each loop would work as don't want to do it on all sheets.  That was my original thought.  But suppose I could use the for each one for my list on the other sheet.

Comment: You can just use `If sht.Name <> "Sheet1" And sht.Name <> "Sheet2" Then ...` inside the loop, if you want to exclude sheets... or prefix the sheets and use `If Left(sht.Name, 2) <> "xx" Then ...`